# How could i improve my opencv program to detect only the crosswalk?

Tags: python, opencv, detect

I would like to detect the pedestrian crossing in the image below, and fill it with red color, but the program detect other things too. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("zebra_lane.jpg")
cv2.imshow("kep" ,img)
imgContour=img.copy()

def getContours(img, imgContour):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    for cnt in contours:
        area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area>500:
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # peri=cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
            # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*peri,True)
            # # print(len(approx))
            # if len(approx)==4:
            #     x,y,w,h =cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            #     cv2.rectangle(imgContour,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255),1)


imgblur=cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),1)
imggray=cv2.cvtColor(imgblur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


imgcanny=cv2.Canny(imggray,150,90)
cv2.imshow("kep" ,imgcanny)

kernel=np.ones((1,1))
imgDil = cv2.dilate(imgcanny,kernel,iterations=1)
cv2.imshow("kep" ,imgDil)


getContours(imgDil,imgContour)
cv2.imshow("contour",imgContour)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  Do you want to isolate out the pedestrian walking area?

Comment: The expected output is to fill the white crossing with red, but only the crossing.

Comment: Threshold on the white/gray walk. Then get contours of those only and filter on size of the contours to throw out small ones. Then if you want the full extent, you can get the convex hull to combine the regions.

Comment: use AI. semantic segmentation. -- "traditional" approaches will simply not work. this requires AI.

Comment: Follow the approach by @fmw42. It's a very sensible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Threshold on the white/gray sidewalk stripes
- Apply morphology open and close
- Get external contours
- Filter contours on area and keep good contours
- Draw good contours on input
- Combine contours
- Compute convex hull of combined contours
- Draw convex hull on input
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('walkway.jpg')

# threshold on white/gray sidewalk stripes
lower = (100,130,130)
upper = (180,200,200)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)


# apply morphology close to fill interior regions in mask
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# filter on area
contours = img.copy()
good_contours = []
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 200:
        cv2.drawContours(contours, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 1)
        good_contours.append(c)

# combine good contours
contours_combined = np.vstack(good_contours)

# get convex hull
result = img.copy()
hull = cv2.convexHull(contours_combined)
cv2.polylines(result, [hull], True, (0,0,255), 2)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("walkway_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("walkway_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("walkway_contours.jpg", contours)
cv2.imwrite("walkway_result.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MORPH", morph)
cv2.imshow("CONTOURS", contours)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology image:

[image]

Contour image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Omg thank you very much! the "Contour image" is what i wanted. The rectangles just need to be filled with red color and done.

Comment: Since this was for class work, what did you learn new from my post.

Comment: Many useful things.