# Find and color a Pedestrian crossing

Tags: python, opencv, colors, contour, threshold

I have a task, where I need to find in Python on a picture a pedestrian crossing and color it to red.

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np

# Let's load a simple image with 3 black squares
image = cv2.imread('crosswalk.jpg')
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 161, 550)

# Finding Contours


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,
                                       cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))


cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)



cv2.imshow('Contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('Binary Threshold', thresh1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code and right now I'm on this level.

[image]

How could I decrease the contours to the required area and than color it to red?

Thank you

Comment: Filter by contour area. Keep only the largest contours above a minimum threshold. Also note that the contours you are looking for have certain aspect ratio (one dimension is larger than the other). This can help you to further filter the target contours/blobs.

Comment: Search this forum. I answered a similar question with the same image. OK. I found it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989250/how-could-i-improve-my-opencv-program-to-detect-only-the-crosswalk/71990558#71990558

Comment: the picture in this question is the same used in the previous question. are you two taking the same class?